# How to get the width of a d3 chart after updating?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'd like to get the width of the main `<g>` element after expanding nodes in a collapsible tree.

As can be expected, the structure is `#tree > svg > g > ...`. It's the width of that first `<g>` that I want. While I can get it with `d3.select('#map>svg>g')` (and then calling `.getBBox().width`, I want the width as it is *after expanding a clicked-on branch*. `d3.select('#map>svg>g')` gives the the width as it was *before* expanding. ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/okUxAvE/14/edit?js,console,output))

Looking at the console output in the demo (`console.log()` is on line 156), it's clear that clicking expands or collapses the tree, which of course changes the width of the `<g>`, but the newer value is only shown upon the *next* click event.

Am I checking for the width too early? Do I need to update something to make the "new" width available in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a transition which animates the expansion of the node. So when you're checking it, nothing has happened yet. You can however use `setTimeout` to delay the checking until the transition has completed.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var c = d3.select('#map>svg>g'),
      curWidth = c[0][0].getBBox().width;
  console.log(curWidth);
}, duration);
```